# Why there is output by pressing enter , without reaching EOF in file copy program ,example in the book "THE C PROGRAMMING LANGUGE BY DENNIS RITCHIE"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
putchar(c);
}
```

WHILE WE WRITE SOMETHING , PROGRAMME GIVES OUTPUT AFTER PRESSING ENTER, INSTEAD OF GIVING OUTPUT AFTER REACHING EOF.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT!

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

`putchar(c);` reserves the right to write the character to the standard output (possibly, in other words, your *terminal*) whenever it pleases, so long as it doesn't jumble up the order on that thread.

Normally in the case of the standard output stream, the C runtime will *buffer* the output, and flush that buffer when a newline character is encountered.

Comment: please explain thoroughly, i am new to programming